# Set values of list of Material UI Autocompletes that fetch options dynamically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a [Material UI Autocomplete combo-box](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box) child component class that fetches results as the user types:

```
...
fetchIngredients(query) { 
    this.sendAjax('/getOptions', {
      data: {
        q: query
      }
    }).then((options) => {
      this.setState({
        options: options
      });
    });
}
...
<Autocomplete
    options={this.state.options}
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={(e, val) => {
       this.setState({value: val});
    }}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
      this.fetchIngredients(newInputValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => {
      // Hidden input so that FormData can find the value of this input.
      return (<TextField {...params} label="Foo" required/>);
    }}
    // Required for search as you type implementations:
    // https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#search-as-you-type
    filterOptions={(x) => x}
/>
...
```

This child component is actually rendered as one of many in a list by its parent. Now, say I want the parent component to be able to set the value of each autocomplete programmatically (e.g., to auto-populate a form). How would I go about this?

I understand I could lift the `value` state up to the parent component and pass it as a prop, but what about the `this.state.options`? In order to set a default value of the combo-box, I'd actually need to also pass a single set of options such that `value` is valid. This would mean moving the ajax stuff up to the parent component so that it can pass `options` as a prop. This is starting to get really messy as now the parent has to manage multiple sets of ajax state for a list of its Autocomplete children.

Any good ideas here? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are children components making up a form, then I would argue that hoisting the value state up to the parent component makes more sense, even if it does require work refactoring. This makes doing something with the filled-in values much easier and more organized.

Then in your parent component, you have something like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    values: [],
    options: []
  };
}

const fetchIngredients = (query, id) => { 
  this.sendAjax('/getOptions', {
    data: {
      q: query
    }
  }).then((options) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      [id]: options
    });
  });
}

const setValue = (newValue, id) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    ...prevState,
    [id]: newValue
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
      ...
      {arrOfInputLabels.map((label, id) => (
        <ChildComponent 
          id={id}
          key={id}
          value={this.state.values[id]}
          options={this.state.options[id]}
          fetchIngredients={fetchIngredients}
          labelName={label}
        />
      )}
      ...
    </>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically it sounds like I'm just going to have to hoist the state up and maintain it at a higher level, even it complicates the design and feels a bit dirty (IMO). This is really the only way to be able to "control" state of the the child component.

Comment: It definitely is not the only way, but to maintain many input fields on the same page (and especially if you want to do anything with the values of them), hoisting them to the shared parent component is a good method in my experience and to my understanding. You could also use the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook for example, but it wouldn't be my first choice with something like this. Feel free to consider that as well, though, since you know your application best.